# Not getting the user ip due to nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, ip, clientip

I am using the node as backend server and using the nginx as a reverse proxy server.

I want to store the user ip address on my db. For that I searched on the blogs and forum and found [public-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/public-ip) npm module

After that I tested on server and found that this module will return my EC2 instance public ip instead of user public IP.

After finding this issue on internet and again found that this may be due to using the reverse proxy.

For that I need to add the this code under the location block which I already did.

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

And need to add this code on my express server

```
app.set('trust proxy', true)
```

And call this to grab the IP

```
req.header('x-forwarded-for') or req.connection.remoteAddress
```

> Update
> This is my nginx config

```
location / {
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        }
My proxy_params is
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

I need to ask how I can use this inside some function or Any API calls. Is it surely return me the client IP?

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your nginx configruation.

Comment: @Marc I have updated it on the question

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

*nginx config*:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name nodeapp;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

*Express app*:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', true);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let ip = req.ip;
    if (ip.substr(0, 7) == '::ffff:') {
        ip = ip.substr(7);
    }
    console.log(ip);
    res.end(ip);
});

app.listen(8000, console.log('listening on 8000'));
```

**EDIT:** **I made some error in the nginx config, fixed it.**

Comment: IF this is like this then Should I need to use request-ip module or should I remove it from my package

Comment: Actually I updated the answer so check it out.

Comment: So it means public-ip module is not used here. So I can uninstall from my server?

Comment: I tired and it returns on 127.0.0.1 on development. Not tested on production.
I have a question that Its like the dependency that I need to start the nginx server because if I close the nginx server then I am getting the error.

Comment: I think try logging `XFF` header to the console because that worked atleast for me. The Ip could also be the second one in the list. Also, please update your question with the exception.